# Differences between emulator layout and phone layout

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem, because I can't understand why the layout of my app is different when I run it on my phone. The buttons are moved a bit to the right. Screenshot at the link:

[image: screenshot from phone]

On emulator it looks correctly, the items are centered. I'm using Visual Studio Express.

```
<Page
x:Class="App6.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App6"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0.333,0,-0.333" Width="400">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="59*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="625*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Kliknij" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Click="Button_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.585,-5.095" Margin="146,499.253,145,69" Grid.Row="1"  />
    <TextBlock x:Name="costam" Margin="96,202.253,102,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" FontSize="36" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="202" Text="kj." Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button x:Name="schowaj" Content="Schowaj" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="139,410.253,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="schowaj_Click" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="wpisz" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="139,297.253,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button x:Name="zamien" Content="Zamień" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="139,351.253,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="zamien_Click" Grid.Row="1"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you post the XAML code?

Comment: No problem. I've posted the code

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you give screen shot of emulator screen?

Comment: I want it to look like this (the lowest button is centered): [link](http://zapodaj.net/d12f6f880cd57.png.html)

Comment: Don't use hard coded margins if not really needed. If you want something centered then use HorizontalAlignment = center, also take advantage of columns and rows when needed. This will help you to position elements regardless the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator you use probably has a different resolution or screen size that your device. The main problem is you are using margins to position your element, which is totally wrong and resolution/screen size dependent. Just us a Grid and split it into a few rows.